# Make animation class ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiviewanimation

Is there anyway to make a class in iOS that then animates something? I know little to nothing about UIView animations and I want to know if it is possible and how. This is what I would like to turn into a class:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                 animations:^{

                     X = X + 19
                 }
                 completion:nil];
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why would you want that? What are you planning to animate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know whether this is the best way but one way to do it is: create an objective-c class (subclass of UIView). Do your initializations in the initialization method. Then create an instance method where your put your animation code. eg

```
-(void)startAnimation{   

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
             animations:^{  
        cg_point= self.center; 
        cg_point.x=cg_point.x+19;
        self.center=cg_point;

    }completion:nil];

}
```

You call this method in your main view controller whenever required to do the animation.